# How can I calculate the ratio of the line segments in the following geometric scene?

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

The following code can draw the corresponding geometric scene. By observing for many times, we can know that the length ratio of line `CE` and line `DE` is fixed. How can I find the length ratio of them?

```
FindGeometricConjectures[
  RandomInstance[
    GeometricScene[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, 
      {Triangle[{"A", "B", "C"}], 
       GeometricAssertion[{"C", "E", "D"}, "Collinear"], 
       GeometricAssertion[{"A", "D", "B"}, "Collinear"], 
       EuclideanDistance["A", "D"] == 2 EuclideanDistance["D", "B"], 
       Triangle[{"A", "E", "D"}], Triangle[{"B", "E", "D"}], 
       PlanarAngle[{"A", "E", "B"}] == 135 °}]]]
```